# How to make API request with bearer token from anyone around the world?

Tags: api, server, ip, access-token, bearer-token

I am a newbie in integrating APIs and so I am encountering some issues that need help.I have been working with Clash of Clans API for some weeks. I want to make a website where users can make request and get data from the server. **To use the API, a JSON Web Token is required and it needs to be passed as part of every request. The token is bound to rate limitations and specified IP addresses. **
What I have been doing is, create a token with my IP address, get the token and make request using it. Now, I want to take this a step forward but I have no idea how to take request from users around the world.

I thought of taking keyword from the user and making request from the server but don't know the step forward. Or maybe I should make requests using my server's address from my PC? Which I don't know how. I will appreciate it if someone could explain to me with this in layman's language and if possible through a reference. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to design for Clash of Clans API architecture.

I just to make a simple design base on quick review of Clash of Clans limitation.
API_KEY can add IP address only when create API_KEY.
It means can't update (add) user IP address after create API_KEY.

[image]

### Step 0 : Create API_KEY

Clash of Clans server only allow specified IPs and API_KEY for REST API call.
You need to know your server IP v4 address(production purpose) and your IP address(debugging purpose)

your IP address get from google search
[image]

After create key, you (developer), develop(or debugging) your API.
This is created API KEY in CC server
[image]

This example, using Postman check API.
[image]

### Step 1 : User login

With his User ID and password. it will save into your server with hashed value.
(It means not save password, save hashed data). it can verify but if leak to hacker much more safe.
Use request API call(or service) to your server

### Step 2 : Your server forward API to CC server

Server verify user is valid
If valid user, server forward API call into Clash of Clans(CC) server by CC API with API_KEY(Bearer Token)

### Step 3 : CC server  check correct API call

CC server verify by compare called API_KEY/IP address with saved API_KEY/IP address

### Step 4 : CC server  return API response to your server

Your server received the server API call

### Step 5 : Your server return to user

User received her request a service

### This API list

You can test it from your home.

[image]

This is example API call via CC server's documentation
[image]

Comment: How can I get the ip address of a server? E.g: firebase. I did `ping <a firebase hosted website>` and got an ip 199.36.158.100. Is this it?

Comment: @BishwoBista, I have no experence a `firebase` but ping is not a your server IP address. It will be get by static IP address setting.
https://medium.com/@scorpion.nimit/how-to-create-a-firebase-cloud-function-with-static-outbound-ip-8086bbbdbbfe
https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses/reserve-static-external-ip-address